# Angular cli configure path alias

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

In my project I have the fallowing folder structure
[image]

The background.component.scss has the fallowing code:

```css
.modal-overlay {
  background: url(assets/img/bg-image.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
}
```

Running the ng serve I have the fallowing error:

> ERROR in
>   ./node_modules/custom-repo/javascript/background.component.css Module
>   not found: Error: Can't resolve './assets/img/bg-image.png' in '/site/node_modules/custom-repo/javascript'

I know there is a folder structure problem! but the question is if there's any workaround? Since it's an external module and I can't change the folder structure.
Can I set an **ALIAS** to **match "site/node_modules/custom-repo/javascript" to "site/node_modules/custom-repo/resources"**??

The angular.cli looks like this:
[image]

Comment: What does the "styles" and "assets" sections of your .angular-cli.json file look like?

Comment: Hi @DeborahK,I have the fallowing structure:
"apps": [
{
"root": "src",
"outDir": "compiled",
"assets": [
  { "glob": "**/*", "input": "resources/assets", "output": "assets" }
],
"styles": [
  "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css" 
]

Comment: Edited the question with the angular-cli. Sorry for the previous format!